# How to replace single blackslash in ruby

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have been trying something like this to replace blackslash with a word:

```
str ="\"
str.gsub!("\", "\add")
```

no luck so far. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Try entering the following from the command line in the terminal: `ruby -e "str = "\"`. It will return, `"-e:1: unterminated string meets end of file"`. The `-e` flag instructs Ruby to run the code that's contained in the string following `-e`. The reason that you get the error message is that Ruby reads the double quote that begins the string, then reads the (single) character `\"`, which is a double quote, but since it is escaped, it does not terminate the string.  You get the exception because the string has no closing double quote.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow suggests the problem.  Your initial backslash isn't escaped!

```
str.gsub("\\","\\add")
```

**edit for clarification**:

```
2.2.0 :002 > str = "\\"
 => "\\" 
2.2.0 :003 > str.gsub("\\","\\add")
 => "\\add"
```

Comment: I got the following error:: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting end-of-input
str.gsub("\\","\\add")

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

> `str = "\\"`
>
> `str.gsub!("\\", "add")`
>
> `print str`

Answer (score 0):

"\" does not exist in a ruby string

```
str ="RU\BY"
puts str
```

will print RUBY

You only can use `"\\"` so the answer is str.gsub!(`"\\"`,"`\\`add")